# How to order a table based on the value of an instance method of a separate but associated table?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Using Rails, how can I order a table based on an instance method of another table that belongs_to the first table?

To illustrate:

**models/state.rb**

```
has_many :weathers
```

**models/weather.rb**

```
belongs_to :state

def intensity
  #some calculation
end
```

**schema**

```
create_table "weathers"
  t.string "name"
end
```

So, let's say all `:states` have a `:weather` with `name: "snow"`. (They are seperate records, with different values of `intensity`, but they have the same `name`). How could I list all the states, ordered by `@state.weathers.find_by(name: "snow").intensity`?

Comment: why wouldn't you store intensity as a property of :weather? your calculation would probably base on something within a :weather anyway ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use joins:

```
@states = State.joins(:weathers).where("weathers.name = ?", "snow")
  .sort_by do |x, y|
    x.weathers.map(&:intensity).max <=> y.weathers.map(&:intensity).max
  end
```

Sorry, you must sort the data with ruby. I supouse you sort with the max intensity because you can have more than one weather for each state.